# Wiring problem while making couple of USB Type-C cables

Tags: usb, wiring, cables, pinout

### 1. USB TYPE-C to USB 2.0 Standard-A Cable

[image]

Found this TYPE-C connector parts w/ 56k resistor from taobao, but there is no detailed circuit diagram on it.

I want to make USB TYPE-C(device) to USB 2.0 Standard-A(host) Cable with this.

USB type-c specification document says,

> Pin A5 (CC) of the USB Type-C plug shall be connected to VBUS through a resistor Rp (56 kΩ ± 5%).

**Question A : Can I assume that the 56k resistor is used for PULL-UP resistor as the spec requires?**

And the connector has two copper pads for each of VBUS, GND respectively.

**Question B : Should I connect both side of copper pads for VBUS and GND? or Can I ignore the opposite side for each of them?**

**Question C : Should I avoid 10NF capacitor for this type of cable?**

---

### 2. USB Type-C to USB 3.1 Standard-B Cable

[image]

Also found this TYPE-C connector parts w/ 5.1k resistor and 10nf capacitor,
and sure enough, there is no detailed circuit diagram on it.

I want to make USB Type-C(host) to USB 3.1 Standard-B(device) Cable with this.

USB type-c specification document says,

> Pin A5 (CC) of the USB Type-C plug shall be connected to GND through a resistor Rd (5.1 kΩ ± 20%).
>
> All VBUS pins shall be connected together within the USB Type-C plug. A bypass capacitor is
>   required between the VBUS and ground pins in the USB Type-C plug side of the cable. The bypass
>   capacitor shall be 10nF ± 20% in cables which incorporate a USB Standard-B plug. The bypass
>   capacitor shall be placed as close as possible to the power supply pad.

**Question D : Can I assume that the 5.1k resistor is used for PULL-DOWN resistor as the spec requires?**

**Question E : Can I assume that the 10nf capacitor is used for bypass capacitor as the spec requires?**

**Question F : Can I ignore copper pad for CC? (leave opened)**

---

I'm especially worried about the second one, cause someone said this can fry my laptop up if I choose the wrong parts.

Anyway, thank you for reading this.

Comment: Don't buy parts without a datasheet.

Comment: @DKNguyen Okay. but honestly, I'm little bit frustrated cause no dealer I can reach provides datasheets or circuits..